# EA killed my Bioware keys

Tags: technical-issues

In Bioware's pre-EA era they had on their site the option to register CD-keys for your Bioware games. Me, being the optimist that I am, registered my cd-keys there and then promptly lost the hard copy that was included with the retail box.

Today I decided that it would be fun to replay the original Neverwinter Nights campaign and went to Bioware's site to get the CD key. Much to my dismay it would appear that all of the old site has been replaced with the new EA Bioware/Social site; this means that only current EA owned Bioware games are able to be registered. In a frantic search of the new site I was unable to locate any reference to the ability to register or retrieve cd-keys to Biowares stable of older games.

So, am I blind and just missed an obvious link to these old keys or did EA go out of its way to inconvenience everyone that had done as I did?

Comment: I would recommend contacting them, since you registered the keys with them I would imagine they would be willing to help you recover them.

Comment: Slightly off topic here: This is one of the reasons why so many people pirate games. It's so much easier to just grab a keygen off any random website than to go through the hassle of customer service. The companies themselves are at fault half the time when people pirate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They've had to take down the server due to a hacking attempt; it sounds like they are working on restoring access once they can ensure it will be secure.

(See http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/6/index/7664680 ).

Comment: Also includes a number for customer service, if he wants to call instead of email - 1-866-543-5435.

Answer (score 7):

I'm sure EA didn't "go out of its way" - it just hasn't been maintaining an old website that hadn't been visited frequently.

You should contact customer service. I would imagine they still have these old records, even if the site has long since gone kaput.

There is a "Contact Us" link on http://support.ea.com/.

Comment: Un-surprisingly the EA site does not have Neverwinter Nights in its cataloge of games, thus I was unable to ask a question about it through the "Contact Us" link. However, on the Bioware site they linked to "webmaster@bioware.com" for questions or issues with the site. So I emailed that address and hopefully they'll have a positive response.